# Why does a SELECT INTO sql statement give me an error in this Pl/SQL Function?

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I am trying to create a pl/sql function to calculate the total of all salaries in an employee table and return it. I am using the sum function but i am getting an error

I have tried changing the sql statement to this solution provided a stack overflow

```
SELECT (select sum(salary) from employee) INTO total_sum FROM dual;
```

Below is a sum statement working

```
SQL> select sum(salary) from employee;

SUM(SALARY)
-----------
281000
```

Here is the Pl/SQL Function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION total_salary(dep_number IN NUMBER)
RETURN NUMBER
IS
total_sum NUMBER;
BEGIN
SELECT (select total_sum sum(salary) from employee) INTO total_sum FROM     dual;
return total_sum;
END total_salary;
```

Here is the error
Warning: Function created with compilation errors.

```
SQL> show errors
Errors for FUNCTION TOTAL_SALARY:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
6/1      PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
6/29     PL/SQL: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
```

I expect the function to return the sum of the salary

Comment: I guess there's just one `total_sum` too many. Try `... (select sum(salary) ...`...

Comment: Is the total_sum another column?

Comment: No, i was declaring it as of type NUMBER

Comment: You need to tell us how your function works. For example, take the dept_number as the input then return the sum(salary) for that specific department.

Comment: Yes, It was to take the department number then select total sum for that department, i removed the WHERE dep_id = ' ' while debugging

Comment: It is result of all the salaries in that department added together

Comment: Yes It works, Ive tried to up-vote the answer but i still have not earned enough reputation, thanks for your assistance.

Comment: Please see the update. You can accept the answer by clicking the 'check' below the 'vote' area (no matter how much the reputation you have)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION total_salary(dep_number IN NUMBER) 
   RETURN NUMBER 
   IS total_sum NUMBER;
   BEGIN 
      SELECT SUM(salary) 
      INTO total_number 
      FROM employee
      WHERE deptid = dep_number; 
      RETURN(total_sum); 
    END;
```